# How to remove fbLocationList from Firebug extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am modifying firepath a firebug extension, my work is almost done, but I couldn't find any way to remove fbLocationList - the first combo box with searchable text box. I searched through all the files but it was neither enabled anywhere nor disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fbLocationButtons` element, which contains the `fbLocationList` element is [collapsed by default](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/a1bbd1fd39b8af111dc7c073de46ecc73bea4c0f/extension/content/firebug/firebugOverlay.xul#L355) and just displayed in case the panel has a [location defined](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/7d35a97e0eb444f12317b3240f43f9ea55888433/extension/content/firebug/chrome/chrome.js#L964).

So I assume you just need to remove the logic adding the `location` property to the panel, if you don't want to have the Location Menu displayed at all.

For reference, the same thread was opened [in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/EyWXt94h1aA/discussion).

Sebastian